# how to connect to cassandra cluster using cqlsh or command prompt?

Tags: cassandra

In other dbs, we connect to db cluster with load balance IP. How do we connect to cassandra cluster using command line? What socket is used? Is this always a single node and IP?
What if i connect o node1, and node1 goes down. Will this automatically connect to node2 or node3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several options: the easiest one is to use the Cassandra Query Language Shell ([CQLSH](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useStartingCqlshTOC.html)), which is a python based CQL interpreter to interact with Cassandra. It usually comes with every Cassandra installation, under the **/bin** folder of the installation directory. If you have ssh access to one of the nodes Cassandra is running onto, this can be an easy option (you will avoid any issues related to firewall blocking incoming connections to your cluster).

You can also use cqlsh to access remotely to the cluster:

```
cqlsh node_ip 9043
```

but this will require cqlsh to be present on your machine.

In general, Cassandra uses an initial set of contact nodes and a gossip protocol to contact and learn the cluster composition. You will be assigned a node as coordinator for your query. You may not worry about seed nodes being currently down, provided that at least one is up and running.

Another option to access remotely to the cluster is the Datastax [DevCenter](https://academy.datastax.com/downloads/ops-center?destination=downloads/ops-center&dxt=DevCenter#devCenter),which is a free-to-use grafical interface to execute CQL queries.

Hope this helps

Comment: I got you. But my concern is what if the node I'm connected to, goes down/crashed. How will client connect to other node?

Comment: [Here](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/how-cassandra-deals-with-replica-failure) you can find details on how failures are managed during requests. I don't know the CQLSH behavior in case of failure of the contacted node or coordinator. I can suppose after a first query is performed the tool "learns" the cluster and lets you retry your query. I think that DevCenter would allow you to do this since you can provide a set of seed nodes instead of a single one.